# this following code is not run by GPU but my original code with mnist run with gpu?

Tags: keras, gpu, conv-neural-network, mnist, tf.keras

my original keras.Tensorflow 2.0 is run by GPU 
but i try to run this code

```
for label in range(10):
    print('***** label {} *****'.format(label))
    y_c = model.output[0, label]
    grads = keras.backend.gradients(y_c, model.input)[0]
    saliency = keras.backend.function([model.input], [grads])

    idx_coord = np.where(y_test == label)[0]
    X = np.zeros((batch_size, 28, 28, 1))
    for batch in range(batch_size):
        X[batch,...,0] = x_test[idx_coord[batch]]/255

    Y = np.array([[1 if label==i else 0 for i in range(10)] for _ in range(batch_size)])

    for batch in tqdm.trange(batch_size):
        x_input = X[batch,...,0].copy()
        y_input = Y[batch].copy()

        score_list = []
        if isplot:
            plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))

        for it in range(iteration):
            score = model.evaluate(x_input[np.newaxis,...,np.newaxis], y_input[np.newaxis,...], verbose=0)[1]
            score_list.append(score)

            #img, gradmap =get_gradcam(x_test[idx], model, idx,"conv2d_33")
            gradmap = np.abs(np.squeeze(get_smoothgrad(x_input[np.newaxis,...,np.newaxis], saliency, sigma=sigma)))


            if isplot:
                plt.subplot(1,20,2*(it%10)+1)
                plt.imshow(np.squeeze(x_input))
                plt.subplot(1,20,2*(it%10)+2)
                plt.imshow(np.squeeze(gradmap))
                if it%10 == 9:
                    plt.show()
                    plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))

            coord = np.where(gradmap == gradmap.max())
            x_input[coord] = 0.

        tot_score[label].append(score_list)
```

I'm not sure how this batch thing work with mnist
but gpu is not running with this code

> 1. what is this batch is different then train batch ?
> 2. why this code is not run by gpu?

Comment: can you do a pip freeze and check you have the tensorflow-gpu package installed?

Comment: gpu is working when I just train the regular mnist tranning but above code is not running with gpu